# Use of Core Data model in Widget / Today View Extension?

Tags: ios, ios8, ios-frameworks

I’m building a Today View Extension (Widget) that needs to share data with its containing app. I use heavily core data in the containing app so I would like to use Core Data as a way of sharing a common database between both programs. It means I need to know the object graph model and all the model classes in the widget code too.

In the App Extension Programming guide, Apple says that we should use encapsulate code into Frameworks in order to share it between a containing app and a widget. But in the Framework programming guide, it’s explicitly written that Frameworks should be created only to encapsulate code that is not specific to an application but should encapsulate code that can be reused universaly.

So my questions are:

- Is building a framework encapsulating all my model classes + my core data object model graph is the good way of sharing business logic between a containing app and a widget?
- How would you include a whole Core Data Model into a framework as frameworks don’t seem to be designed to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your criteria and requirements, encapsulating your Core Data stack in an embedded framework target makes sense. I would say that it is not only a good way, but the only way without duplicating the model and logic.

I am not sure what you mean by "frameworks don’t seem to be designed to do that" in your second question. Frameworks are just another target, you should be able to create a Core Data model file whose target membership is your framework's. Then you can have some higher level method in the framework API that returns an `NSManagedObjectContext` based on the model included in the framework.

You are also going to be required to setup an App Group for your underlying persistent store file (typically your sqlite file). In order for your Widget and Containing App to read and write to the same file, that file must be within an App Group that both have entitlements to.